# Synchronizing time in application via JavaScript on iPad

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, time, webforms

Scenario:

I have a iPad web app which connects to my Exchange server to display the visibility of meeting rooms in Outlook.

- The clock must be very accurate (within 5 seconds of the Exchange Server time)

My problem is:

- The iPad syncs its time with apples timeserver and there is no way of changing this without jailbreaking the iPad
- The iPad clock is not in sync with our server

My current solution:

- I have a Clock.aspx page which returns the current time and displays it in the correct div:

  ```
          var getTime = function () {

            $.get('Clock.aspx', function (data) {
                $('#txt').html('<h1>' + data + '</h1>');


            });
           }
  ```

However:

- This is very inefficient as the call to the server is every 10 seconds (this causes the iPad to crash once every 3/4 days)

What I would like to do:

- Is pull the time from Clock.aspx once a hour and increment it using javascript for the rest of the time which will reduce the calls to the server significantly.

Please advise me on the best and most efficient way to do this.

If you have any other suggestions on ways to improve the efficiency I would also love to hear them.

Comment: Why don't you sync your server against a reliable timeserver?

Comment: @rene - there is no setting in the iPad to change the timeserver, you are stuck with Apples timeserver, which may be accurate, but is offset against our servers timeserver (this is not changeable)

Comment: @Corbin, rene was talking about your *Exchange* server, not your iPad.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Unfortunately working for a global organisation these things are not easy to get changed!

Comment: @rene Additionally this would mean giving the iPad access to a proxy server (so it can access apple's timeserver) which we can't do due to security constraints!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - the timeservers are fairly accurate (they are out of sync by about 6 seconds (and some of this time may be a delay from ajax call), however my biggest concern is that I can't access apples proxy server due to security constraints)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - if you are interested in my solution I have added it below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having used my original answer for a few days I noticed that the sync was out, this script sync's with the server time every hour to re-sync the time accordingly, this means that the accuracy of the clock is very very close with the server. The previous script could lose upto 5 minutes per day. I hope this helps someone!

```
  var serverDate;

    function getServerDate() {
    serverDate = new Date("<%=DateTime.Now %>"); 
    }

function tick() {
serverDate.setSeconds(serverDate.getSeconds() + 1);
var min = serverDate.getMinutes();
var hour = serverDate.getHours();
var sec = serverDate.getSeconds();



if (min == 30) {

    $.get('Clock.aspx?type=2', function (data) {

        serverDate = new Date(data.split(">")[1].split("<")[0]);

        min = serverDate.getMinutes();
        hour = serverDate.getHours();
        sec = serverDate.getSeconds();


    });

}

    if (hour < 10) hour = "0" + hour;
    if (min < 10) min = "0" + min;
    if (sec < 10) sec = "0" + sec;

   document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "<h1>" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec; +  "</h1>";


}

window.onload = function () {
getServerDate();
setInterval("tick()", 1000);
}
```

Edited to add that clock.aspx is a page which outputs DateTime.Now.ToString()

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this isn't perfect but meets my requirements for now - I'd once again appreciate it if more efficient and accurate solutions come up!

```
          var hour = parseInt("<%=DateTime.Now.Hour %>", 10);
          var minute = parseInt("<%=DateTime.Now.Minute %>", 10);
          var second = parseInt("<%=DateTime.Now.Second %>", 10);
          //            var x = hour.tostring() +":"+ minute.tostring() +":"+ second.tostring();
          //            alert(x);

          function showTime() {
              second++;
              if (second > 59) {
                  second = 0;
                  minute++;
              }

              if (minute > 59) {
                  minute = 0;
                  hour++;
              }
              minute = checkTime(minute);
              second = checkTime(second);
              var clock = hour.toString() + ":" + minute.toString() + ":" + second.toString();
              document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "<h1>" + clock + "</h1>";
              function checkTime(i) {

                  return (i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i;


              }
          }

          setInterval('showTime()', 1000);
```